# Bible website charset with spanish accents search in MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, character-encoding

I will run a bible website so I created the database with MYSQL default charset latin1_swedish_ci   but the site will be in spanish.

The problem is that the book of Génesis uses accents and so does Éxodo and Josué so when people search for example:

```
$getbook = $_GET['L'];
$bible = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM `bible` WHERE `book` LIKE '%$getbook%'");
```

If people searches for Genesis without accents there are results but if people search for Génesis WITH accent then there are no results.

Here is the script I show results:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';$user = 'username';$pass = 'password';$source = 'this';
$database = @mysqli_connect ($server, $user, $pass, $source) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-15');
$getbook = $_GET['L'];
$bible = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM `bible` WHERE `book` LIKE '%$getbook%'");
while($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bible)) {
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">

<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Chapter</td>
    <td width="10%">Verse</td>
    <td width="80%">Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $show['chapter'] ?></td>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $show['verse'] ?></td>
    <td width="80%"><?php echo $show['text'] ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

The results text are ok the only problem is when you search using accents. It show results for Genesis but not for Génesis with accent.

Here is the real site to test:

```
WITH ACCENT:
http://santabiblia.cl/?L=Génesis 
no results

WITHOUT ACCENT:
http://santabiblia.cl/?L=Genesis 
Yes we have results
```

Any idea?

EDIT

The database looks like

DB_NAME
bible -> book - chapter - verse - text

example

book = Génesis (with accent) chapter = 1 verse = 1 = text = In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth (but in spanish) En el principio, Dios creó los cielos y la tierra.

The MYSQL structure is in latin1_swedish_ci, tested with latin1_spanish_ci and the same problem, tested with UTF8 and it is worse

Comment: What is stored in the database?

Comment: In database the book is stored as Génesis with accent because I need to show then in results the word with accent example ECHO $book

Comment: Right after connecting, do `$database -> set_charset('latin1');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the script that is submitting `L` and URL encode it, while the receiving script URL decodes it.

Comment: how to do this my friend?

Comment: I set $getbook = html_entity_decode($_GET['L']); and it works fine without needing to encode it before. Is that ok or will maybe fail sometimes ?

Comment: Your variable is not URL Encoded it should look like `G%C3%A9nesis` and then you can use 1urldecode($_GET['L'])1

Comment: `G%C3%A9nesis` is automatically converted to `Génesis` before your PHP code sees it.  I don't see how urlencode/urldecode will make any difference.